# Spotify Web-API & Transfer User's Playback : malformed JSON

Tags: javascript, json, spotify

I've been using [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) to interact with Spotify Web API, so far without any trouble.

However, when I try to use the [transferMyPlayback()](https://doxdox.org/jmperez/spotify-web-api-js#src-spotify-web-api.js-constr.prototype.transfermyplayback) method to change the device, I always receive an error response pointing to a malformed JSON.

```
response: "{\n  \"error\" : {\n    \"status\" : 400,\n    \"message\" : \"Malformed json\"\n  }\n}"
```

This method takes a JSON array containing the device ID.

Here's my code for this :

```
    var deviceIds = {}
    deviceIds["device_ids"] = [id]

    var deviceIds_JSON = JSON.stringify(deviceIds)

    spotifyApi.transferMyPlayback(deviceIds_JSON)
      .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
      }, function(err){
        console.log(err)
      });
```

Console.log(deviceIds_JSON) gives something like this :

```
{"device_ids":["948b56d03d394e0533f198152b852eef85799df2"]}
```

I've tried several things to manipulate the JSON, but always end up with an error 400 - malformed JSON message.

I also tried to feed the [Spotify Web-API Console](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/console/put-user-player/) Request Body with the deviceIds_JSON output above, which gives me a curl command ... that works perfectly when executed from console. So, yeah ... I'm a bit confused, there.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where the problem might be ?

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [doc](https://doxdox.org/jmperez/spotify-web-api-js#src-spotify-web-api.js-constr.prototype.transfermyplayback) you should pass an array of string as first argument

Try this:

```
var deviceIds = [id]
spotifyApi.transferMyPlayback(deviceIds)
.then(...)
```

Comment: Damn, I should have paid more attention and stuck to the expected type than the description of the parameter in the doc, I guess -_-
Thanks mate ;)